# After updating Mvvm Light to Version 5, what changes do I need to make RelayCommand CanExecute() work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I updated Mvvm Light to version 5 and noticed that `RelayCommand` stopped working.

The problem seems to be that the `CanExecute()` is not being called to validate. It only validates one time, like when the window is loaded.

Could this be a bug from the recent update or is there something I need to change in the XAML?

Everything was working correctly before the update. I'm working with WPF.

Comment: The same problem, should have found your post before. I had to downgrade back to the previous version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this [MVVM Light 5 issue](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7659):

> WPF is the only XAML framework that uses the CommandManager to
>   automagically raise the CanExecuteChanged event on ICommands. I never
>   liked that approach, because of the "magic" part, but this is a
>   "feature" of WPF and of course I have to support it. No question here.
>
> In V5, I moved to portable class library for all the newest versions
>   of the XAML frameworks, including WPF4.5. Unfortunately, there is no
>   CommandManager in PCL, and I have to admit that I didn't realize that
>   at first sight. So of course now the automagical part doesn't work
>   anymore. Again, so sorry about that.
>
> **I am not expecting you to raise CanExecuteChanged everywhere now**, not
>   after using the CommandManager in your application, which is what the
>   WPF team intended. So I will try to find a way to restore the
>   CommandManager usage in the WPF4.5 version of the toolkit.
>
> Definitely not looking for excuses ;) but hope that explaining why the
>   issue arose helps to make sense of this. It's going to be my priority
>   No. 1 until I find a way to solve this in the PCL version. In the meantime, like I mentioned before, I think that going back to
>   V4.4.32.7 should fix that. Please let me know if it does not.

So the temporary recommended solution is **to revert back to the previous version**. I did it and it worked.

I agree that the CommandManager is doing "magic". Once I had null reference exception within the `CanExecute` condition and as a result I have obtained neverending cycle of error messages like cards in Windows Solitaire. If I started a new project I would prefer not to use this "magic" but to change an existing and already deployed project would be quite painful.

Comment: Fixed in version 5.0.2.

Comment: To use the fix in v5.0.2 be sure to change namespace from GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command; to GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command**Wpf**;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the command whenever a relevant property is changed. I think this was previously done by the wpf command manager, but the recent PCL changes probably made that unsupportable.

I use MvvmCross which requires a similar method to be called, so in my base view model I have a method allowing me to register a command so that whenever a property changed occurs I can loop all registered commands and force canexecute to be called again. To make things easier you could do it that way.

[Check out this sample](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/RaiseCanExecuteChanged/RaiseCanExecuteChanged/ViewModel/MainViewModel.cs)

As this seems to be doubted, here is some code I have tested

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;

namespace TestingApp.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
    /// <para>
    /// Use the <strong>mvvminpc</strong> snippet to add bindable properties to this ViewModel.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// You can also use Blend to data bind with the tool's support.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Int32 _increment = 0;

        public Int32 Increment
        {
            get { return _increment; }
            set
            {
                _increment = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Increment");
                GoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ////if (IsInDesignMode)
            ////{
            ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Code runs "for real"
            ////}
        }

        private RelayCommand _incrementCommand;

        public RelayCommand IncrementCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_incrementCommand == null)
                {
                    _incrementCommand = new RelayCommand(IncrementCommand_Execute);
                }
                return _incrementCommand;
            }
        }

        private void IncrementCommand_Execute()
        {
            Increment++;
        }

        private RelayCommand _goCommand;

        public RelayCommand GoCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_goCommand == null)
                {
                    _goCommand = new RelayCommand(GoCommand_Execute, GoCommand_CanExecute);
                }
                return _goCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool GoCommand_CanExecute()
        {
            return Increment > 5;
        }

        private void GoCommand_Execute()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Without the line

```
GoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

the canexecute method is never called after the initial call, but with the line it is called everytime the Increment property changes

Comment: Maybe if you actually tried what I'd suggested you would have found that I am actually correct. So I would actually consider this a very helpful answer.

I have added some extra sample code which I have tested and it works.

Comment: And imagine you have a project and you must go through hundreds of such cases and test everything again. Would you like to do it?

Comment: I agree it is not preferable for a large project with many commands already, however for any people finding this who are just starting with MVVMLight it could save them time.